# How to make an anthentication flow in ASP.NET Core 8.0 Blazor with external API and jwt token?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

By default, Blazor provides a demo app for Identity. What I want is I have an API project that returns jwt token. Now, I want to create a Blazor App using "**InteractiveAuto**", which means pages can return from the server for the first request and then use web assembly.

Comment: So what did you try? What is the problem? [Here is the .razor page for you.](https://codeshare.io/wnwB4D)

Comment: I've tried to maintain an auth state using AuthenticationStateProvider and local storage to save the token and use it for multiple purposes. like authentication and claims. Local storage throwing an error while reading in the .net 8, without that I'm not sure how to maintain auth state for my jwt barear token. P.S. I want a solution in latest Blazor .net 8.0 not in razor pages

Comment: [Have you checked this document?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-identity-server?view=aspnetcore-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio) And please share more error details, then we can help u better.

Comment: Yes, I read it it's related to the Identity auth and it's in .Net 7. I want jwt token and in .net 8.0

Comment: Do you encounter any specific error messages after you try it?

Comment: Yes,
Error: JavaScript interop Error when calling javascript from OnInitializedAsync Blazor. I use the cascading auth state. thus, GetAuthenticationStateAsync() method auto invoke. There is no matter even I call this on after render.

Answer (score 2):

This seemingly simple requirement is actually fairly complex.  I have not yet found a definitive example posted of the "official" way to do it, but I'll provide some details on an implementation that I have developed.  I'm using OIDC with Azure Entra for the initial signon and then JWT to access the Api, but hopefully you'll be able to adapt some of these ideas to your case.

The primary issue is that we need to handle two authentication cases.  The first  load is using Blazor Server (SSR) and the second load uses WASM.  If you remember back to the old .Net 7 templates, there were two very different flows to implement. The SSR route used IHtttpContextAccessor to access the underlying context.  The WASM route used the MSAL library.

I assume that you already have a method of signing in and a component that looks something like the following:

**ServerProject.Program.cs** (Psuedo code only)

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
   .AddCookies()
   .AddOpenIdConnect()
   .AddJwtBearer()

builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
```

**ClientProject.Program.cs**  (Psuedo code only)

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
```

**AuthorisedComponent.razor**

```
@page "/AuthorisedComponent"
@rendermode InteractiveAuto

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

I have implemented a Custom Authentication State provider to enable the different flows and it looks something like this:

**CustomAuthStateProvider.cs**

```
public class CustomAuthStateProvider :AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly NavigationManager _navMan

    public CustomAuthStateProvider (IHttpConextAccessor httpContextAccessor, NavigationManager navMan)
    { 
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _navMan = navMan;
    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        HttpContext? context = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        ClaimsPrincipal? claimsPrincipal = null;

        if(context != null)  //ie we have a context, so it must be Blazor Server 
        {
             //This is fairly straightforward as we can just retrieve the Claims Principal from the context (and modify it if you like)
              claimsPrincipal = context.User;

             //The biggest downside I have found with this flow is that I can't seem to access Local or Session browser storage
             //I keep getting the Javascript Interop error that you mention.
             //After a bit of research, I think that the issue is that this flow is being called during the OnInitializedAsync lifecycle method.
        }
        else   //ie Blazor WASM  (this will normally be called a few seconds after the Server flow is completed(
        {
            //This is a bit more complicated, and relies on a little trick to retrieve the HttpContext from the server using a call to a controller.

            HttpClient? client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_navMan.BaseUri);
            string? uri = "api/AppAuth/GetClaimsPrincipal_WASM";

            HttpResponseMessage? response = await client.PostAsync(uri, null);
            string? responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            AppClaimsPrincipalDTO = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AppClaimsPrincipalDTO>(responseString);

            claimsPrincipal = AppClaimsPrincipalDTO?.ToClaimsPrincipal() ?? new();
            //Note: I have found it is possible to access browser storage here without Javascript Interop error if you need to.
        }

        return new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal);
    }
```

It is possible to retrieve the httpcontext if a request is made to a controller in your backend.
Credit to:  [Damien Boden - Backend for Front End Auth](https://damienbod.com/2023/02/14/use-multiple-identity-providers-from-a-blazor-wasm-asp-net-core-app-secured-using-bff/)  for this idea.

**AppAuthController.cs**

```
public class AppAuthController : Controller
{

    [AllowAnonomous]
    [HttpPost("api/AppAuth/GetClaimsPrincipal_WASM")
    public async Task<ActionResult<ClaimsPrincipalDTO>> GetClaimsPrincipal_WASM()
    {
          if (!User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? true)
        {
            var ret = AppClaimsPrincipalDTO.Anonymous();
            return Ok(ret);
        }
        else
        {         
           AppClaimsPrincipalDTO ret = new ();
           //get claims from User
           {
               {
                   ret.IsAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
                   var claims = User.Claims.ToList();

                   foreach (Claim? claim in claims)
                   {
                       var claimDto = new AppClaimDTO();
                       claimDto.Type = claim.Type;
                       claimDto.Value = claim.Value;
                       claimDto.ValueType = claim.ValueType;
                       claimDto.Issuer = claim.Issuer;
                       ret.AppClaims.Add(claimDto);
                   }

                   foreach (AppClaimDTO? claimDTO in customClaims)
                   {
                       ret.AppClaims.Add(claimDTO);
                   }
               }
           }

           return Ok(ret);     
        }
    }

} 


public class AppClaimsPrincipalDTO
{
    public static AppClaimsPrincipalDTO Anonymous() => new();
    public bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; } = false;
    public string NameClaimType { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string RoleClaimType { get; set; } = string.Empty;



    /// <summary>
    /// Custom AppClaims that are to be added to the ClaimsPrincipal in AuthenticationStateProvider and OnTokenValidation for Bearer_Server
    /// </summary>
    public IList<AppClaimDTO> AppClaims { get; set; } = new List<AppClaimDTO>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Take  a base Claims Principal and adds the AppClaims to it
    /// </summary>
    public ClaimsPrincipal ToClaimsPrincipal()
    {
        //create anonymous identity
        ClaimsIdentity newIdentity = new();

        if (AppClaims.Any())
        {
            newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(nameof(AppClaimsPrincipalDTO), NameClaimType, RoleClaimType);

            var claims = new List<Claim>();

            foreach (AppClaimDTO claimDTO in AppClaims)
            {
                claims.Add(claimDTO.ToClaim());
            }
            newIdentity.AddClaims(claims);
        }

        var ret = new ClaimsPrincipal(newIdentity);
        return ret;
     }
}

public class AppClaimDTO
{
    public string Type { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Value { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ValueType { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Issuer { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public Claim ToClaim()
    {
        return new Claim(Type, Value, ValueType, Issuer);
    }
}
```

There are quite a few different concepts here and I've distilled a fairly large chunk of code into the essential elements and removed error handling etc., but hopefully you can get the general idea.

I know this use case is a bit different to yours, but hopefully you can work out where to inject your JWT tokens to call the API in this flow.  You only provided limited detail, so I've had to make a lot of assumptions about your your implementation.

I have got this "working", but there seems to be a fair bit of redundant computation since we need to do auth for both Server and WASM.  It is also much more complicated than it should be for such a fundamental requirement.  I hope that an official template is issued soon so that we can see how the makers intended it to be used.